# Way to get some sort of schedule in TCL without blocking on-going code

Tags: task, tcl, schedule

I need some sort of schedule thing to schedule a task to happen at x:y (12:00 for example) in Tcl.
The scenario is a router using Openwrt with Tcl 8.6.10 with limited RAM and storage where I have some sort of IRC client "bot" (using socket to connect). The "bot" was just a barebone that I modify to suit my needs. Most of the things work fine, except that I don't have way to schedule easily things. I wanted something like how eggdrop has "bind time" where the bind thing is "bind time flag "cron-style string" caller".

The "bot" scheme is like:

Main Tcl script:

```
<info+code to connect to IRC>
<while loop>
 <some code in case of IRC disconnection>
 <list of files with tcl code aka sub-scripts>
 <usage of source based from a list of the filenames>
 <code for error handling>
<end of while loop>
```

The list of files is source filelist.tcl, where filelist.tcl is a set var {filename1.tcl filename2.tcl...}. The filenamex.tcl has some basic code to respond to IRC server or IRC input from channels and reply to channels.

I can make some sort of schedule if I base a execution like if {[clock format [clock seconds] -format "%H:%M"]=="12:00"} {code to execute} and hopefully wait for a server ping/pong but that can lead to repeated code inside of the if body.

I been looking around and found a package called cron but I don't know how to use it correctly because there are not many examples and I don't know to use vwait properly and I don't want vwait to hang the bot waiting for a value to change. I also read about tcl threads for maybe parallel execution.

So I need some code inside of a sub-script that looks like (a package cron style):

```
#beginning of file
#add a task specifying hour and minute
task-at "12:00" proccaller

proc procname {optional} {
 <some code to be executed at specific hour+time>
}
#end of file
```

I also don't know how to use after command to use it.
How can I accomplish I want?

Comment: Rewrite your code to use the event loop, and schedule stuff with `after`. https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/event%2Doriented+programming?R=0 is a starting point for learning about it.

Comment: Using a coroutine may also help; that lets non-trivial main loops become event-oriented without having to manually contort them into continuation-passing form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies and yes, it would help if I study event loops and coroutine, which probably comes next.

Some time has passed since I posted the question and kinda sorted the thing by creating a sub-script in a folder named scripts with the following structure:

```
#beginning of the script
if {![file exists executed]} {set executed "no"}
#the following clock instruction returns for example: Tuesday 22:14
switch -glob -- [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%A %H:%M"] {
  "*12:00" - "*12:01" {
  #Basic example of sending a message to the irc channel when it's midday
    if {$executed=="no"} {
      puts $fd "PRIVMSG #CODE :It's midday right now."
      flush $fd
      set executed "yes"
    }
  }
  #...more time comparisions and code
  default {set executed "no"}
}
#end of script
```

And the script is almost the top of the list of scripts to be loaded so if I wish to send some command down stream at giving time, the command can be executed.
There is double timings because the "bot" reacts, at least at minimum, to the irc server's ping which happens each 90 seconds and it may skip some minutes.
This is not an answer but an unproper workaround.